# Error connecting to linked server after recompile

Tags: .net, sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a ASP.NET MVC website in IIS 7 running against a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, in which I have a linked server set up.  The linked server is set up so that a SQL account from my database is linked to a SQL account on the linked server.

All works fine until I recompile my website, and then it can't connect to the linked server anymore and I get this error:

Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].

To fix it, I have to open the linked server properties in SQL Server and re-enter the password for the SQL account on the linked server in the Properties dialog and then everything will work again.

Any idea why I have to do this each time and what I can do to fix it?